# How to get data from one RecyclerView and show it in another Activity's RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have an Android nested recycler view in which I am able to show the data now I want to show that data in another activity recycler view. How can I do that?

This is my nested list view:-
[image]

This is where I want to show data in list:-
[image]

Here's my code: my Main Activity:-

```html
package com.saikari.vid.activities;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.saikari.vid.R;
import com.saikari.vid.adapters.VerticalRVAdapter;
import com.saikari.vid.models.HorizontalModel;
import com.saikari.vid.models.VerticalModel;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DatabaseReference dbCategories;

    VerticalRVAdapter adapter;
    RecyclerView verticalRecyclerView;
    ArrayList<VerticalModel> mListData = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        verticalRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        verticalRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        setData();
    }

    private void setData() {
        for (int i = 0; i<10; i++){
            VerticalModel verticalModel = new VerticalModel();
            verticalModel.setCat_title("Title: "+i);

            ArrayList<HorizontalModel> arrayListHorizontal = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int j = 0; j<10; j++){
                HorizontalModel horizontalModel = new HorizontalModel();
                horizontalModel.setVid_url("https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300");
                horizontalModel.setVid_title("Name: "+j);

                arrayListHorizontal.add(horizontalModel);
            }

            verticalModel.setVidArrayList(arrayListHorizontal);
            mListData.add(verticalModel);
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

Vertical RecyclerView adapter class:-

```html
public class VerticalRVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VerticalRVAdapter.VerticalRVViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<VerticalModel> arrayList;

    public VerticalRVAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<VerticalModel> arrayList){
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public VerticalRVViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_vertical,parent,false);
        return new VerticalRVViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull VerticalRVViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final VerticalModel verticalModel = arrayList.get(position);
        String title = verticalModel.getCat_title();
        final ArrayList<HorizontalModel> singleItem = verticalModel.getVidArrayList();
        holder.titleText.setText(title);
        HorizontalRVAdapter horizontalRecyclerViewAdapter= new HorizontalRVAdapter(context,singleItem);

        holder.recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        holder.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));

        holder.recyclerView.setAdapter(horizontalRecyclerViewAdapter);

        holder.buttonMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, verticalModel.getCat_title(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(context, VideoListActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("catTitle", verticalModel.getCat_title());
                context.startActivity(i);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    public class VerticalRVViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        TextView titleText;
        TextView buttonMore;
        public VerticalRVViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            recyclerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view1);
            titleText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleText);
            buttonMore = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_more);
        }
    }
}
```

Horizontal Recycler View Adapter class:-

```html
public class HorizontalRVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HorizontalRVAdapter.HorizontalRVViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<HorizontalModel> arrayList;

    public HorizontalRVAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HorizontalModel>  arrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public HorizontalRVViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_horizontal,parent,false);
        return new HorizontalRVViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final HorizontalRVViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final HorizontalModel horizontalModel = arrayList.get(position);
        holder.textViewTitle.setText(horizontalModel.getVid_title());
        com.bumptech.glide.Glide.with(context).load(horizontalModel.getVid_url()).into(holder.imageViewThumb);
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, horizontalModel.getVid_url(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(context, YoutubePlayActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("videoID", horizontalModel.getVid_url());
                context.startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    public class HorizontalRVViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView textViewTitle;
        ImageView imageViewThumb;


        public HorizontalRVViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textTitleHorizontal);
            imageViewThumb = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivThumb);
        }
    }
}
```

Data in list activity class (this is the activity where I need to show data):-

```html
public class VideoListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_list);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getIntent().getStringExtra("catTitle"));

    }
}
```

Comment: From what I can understand, you want to show list of `HorizontalModel` items in vertical list in another activity when the user clicks on `more`? Make use of `Parcelable`.

Comment: Yes, can you please provide any reference? like a link to article or video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `Parcelable` on `HorizontalModel` class. If you need help with that check [here](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidParcelable/article.html).

In `VerticalRVAdapter` inside `onBindViewHolder` method

```
holder.buttonMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context, verticalModel.getCat_title(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(context, VideoListActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("catTitle", verticalModel.getCat_title());
            // Put horizontal models in extra bundle
            i.putParcelableArrayListExtra("horizontal_models", singleItem);
            context.startActivity(i);

        }
    });
```

You can now get the bundled `HorizontalModel` list in `VideoListActivity` inside `onCreate` as

```
 ArrayList<HorizontalModel> horizontalModels = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("horizontal_models");
```

You can use this list to populate the vertical list that you want to show.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Just to be sure in mainActivity where I was using Horizontal model I passed "Parcel,obtain()" because its showing error. HorizontalModel horizontalModel = new HorizontalModel(Parcel.obtain()); Hope it's the right way.

Comment: No need to pass `Parcel.obtain`, maybe `HorizontalModel` class is missing a default or empty constructor.